# Location of java.security file used by Rider on Mac

Tags: java, jdbc, rider, mssql-jdbc

When I try to connect to my remote SQL Server database using Rider embedded tools and jdbc sql server driver on a Mac I get the following exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates does not conform to algorithm constraints
```

The algorithm that is problematic is the `MD5withRSA` that is disabled in JRE. I figured out that I need to change the list of disabled algorithms in the `java.security` file. Settings to change:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
```

```
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms
```

The problem is that I can't find java.security file used by the Rider application as JRE is bundled together with the application. How can I change those values or locate the file I need?

I tried using the VM custom settings like the following example, but didn't work:

```
-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=
-Djdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the vm options with the following parameter:

```
-Djava.security.properties=/path/to/my/custom/java.security
```

Content of `/path/to/my/custom/java.security`:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
```